# Can't resize background on responsive layout

Tags: css

I'm working on a clients website and am facing a huge problem. I have a backgroung image that has a repeat-x attribute and I need it to be resized has the window is resized (like a responsive image behaves, but now with a background)

So the code is roughly like this:

```
<style>
body {padding: 0px}
#wrapper { background: url("images/barra.fw.png") repeat-x scroll 0px 115px transparent !important;}
</style>


<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="pagelayout">

    Lorem ipsum

</div>

</div>
```

To clarify all I want is that background image to resize vertically in order to mantain proportions. The website is this one: http://supersorriso.pt.

PS: already tried to mess with everything, can't figure out what wrong, or if this is even possible.

Comment: I don't know which background you want to resize. Can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Solved, check my response below. But thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the `background-size` property on the element that needs its background to be resized.

In your media query:

```
#wrapper{
  background-size:80px 60px;
}
```

You'll need to do the math to get the aspect ratio correct.

Comment: oh, and this only works IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+

Comment: Yay css3! You can polyfill it with js (jQuery) [Perfect Full Size background](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) if you need to support older browsers.

Comment: But skip over the background-size:cover, because it will stretch it across the entire width of the element, rather than tiling it at your specific ratio.

Comment: Well your first tip didn't work. The thing is, this is a horizontally stretching background and that has been a real issue.

Comment: can you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?  So we can see more what you are trying to do?

Comment: Also, the !important at the end could be trumping any modification you are trying to make.

Comment: Ok thanks everybody, solved it using a <img> with absolute positioning. The site is mobile ready now.